# What information do we have about the High Forest, circa DR 1486?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms

I'm looking to learn more about the High Forest, specifically any kingdoms or other settlements in the region. I'm currently running the *Out of the Abyss* adventure, and am anticipating that the PCs may attempt to travel to the High Forest.

What information do we have about the High Forest, circa DR 1486?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most, if not all, of the 5th Edition material pertaining to the High Forest:

- *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* has a [section on the High Forest](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/scag/the-sword-coast-and-the-north#HighForest).
- Players can visit the High Forest in chapter 3 of *Storm Kings Thunder* [The Savage Frontier](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/skt/the-savage-frontier#Chapter3TheSavageFrontier); the section there contains some information, as well as more detailed information on Shadowtop Cathedral.
- *Princes of the Apocalypse* has an entire chapter on [The Dessarin Valley](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/pota/the-dessarin-valley#Chapter2TheDessarinValley), a region bordering the High Forest.
- The 5th level adventure, ["The Price of Beauty"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/cm/the-price-of-beauty#ThePriceofBeauty) from *Candlekeep Mysteries* takes place at the Temple of the Restful Lilly, a grand temple inside the High Forest.